# Error during creating Non-Stock Item (Error: Main Warehouse)

Tags: acumatica

I have fresh install Acumatica ERP without any customization and with following features enabled:
1. Finance
- Standard Financial
-- Multi-Currency Accounting
2. Customer Management
- Lead/Contact Duplicate Validation

When I'm trying to add new Non-Stock item and I select Item Class on details tab, system returns the following error: 'Default Warehouse' cannot be found in the system. Please verify whether you have proper access rights to this object. And it insert 'MAIN" in the item class field.

Any idea, what could be the reason?

Comment: when you say fresh install... is this a clean new install (no snapshot, no demo data) - just a new empty Acumatica database? Also might be helpful to include the Acumatica version you are using

Comment: Also, do you have multi warehouse enabled?

Comment: Hi Brendan, yes I am mean a clean new install without any data or snapshot. And I am using the latest version of Acumatica 6.1 0113. Regarding multi-warehouse, I have not enabled this feature, I have just listed ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to save Inventory Module Preferences. After I done it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to turn multi warehouse feature on and go into the item class to see if it has a value for default warehouse - if it does try to delete the value in the item class and then turn multi warehouse off. Hope that helps. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: I delete the item class but it returns the same error when I am adding new record. If I will leave multi warehouse ON, it works fine, even when default warehouse on item class is empty, but without this feature it returns same error. I try to update item class table manually but nothing helps. 

Did you ever seen error like this in acumatica?

Comment: i have seen strange issues when updating the inventoryitem table where you have to have the INSetup in you graph or the updates might fail. But not your specific scenario. but it would make sense to always have the preferences within a module completed first before moving into other setup areas of a module.